# Identify returning user interaction data from xDB in Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, experience-profile

I have a requirement to identify the returning user which haven't yet created their profile. I know that Sitecore gives the unique identifier to the anonymous user based on the device and stores the information in the cookie.

But when I am trying to get the interactions data from the xConnect API using below code:

```
var session = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction
```

I am only getting the pages from the current visit of the user. Even though I am using the same device and same browser.

How do I get all the previous sessions that visitor has browsed assuming they haven't cleared their browser cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContactRepository` to load previous interactions:

```
ContactRepository contactRepository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository;//or new ContactRepository();
IEnumerable<IInteractionData> lastInteraction = contactRepository.LoadHistoricalInteractions(contactid, visitsToLoad, pastDateTime, currentDateTime);
```

Where:

- `visitsToLoad` - amount of visits that you are interested in.(Could be `int.MaxValue`)
- `pastDateTime` - from what date filter, could be `null`
- `currentDateTime` - to what date filter, could be `null`

Comment: I am getting the below error on the first line
Could not find configuration node: tracking/contactRepository. I had a look into the configuration I can see
<tracking>
<contactManager type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config">...</contactManager>
I am not sure why it is not able to find it.

Comment: Also my xDB index in solr has nothing in it. It doesn't have any documents.

Comment: can you try new ContactRepository() instead of Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository; ?

Comment: It seems to give me the historical interactions. Thanks for the help :)